# Any compact metric space is Borel equivalent to some subset of $[0, 1]$

Tags: metric-spaces

In Petersen's Riemannian Geometry book I encountered the following statement : Any compact metric space $X$ is Borel equivalent to some  $S \subset [0, 1]$ i.e. there is a bijection $f : X \rightarrow S$ which is measurable and whose inverse is also measurable. Frankly speaking I have no clue how to prove this. I know some theorem which says (if I remember correctly) $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Is this of any use here? Can someone give some hint?

Comment: [Section 7.1 of these notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275b.1.13w/PDFs/Standard-Borel-Spaces.pdf) is a nice exposition of a more general result.

Comment: @user147263 link is dead :(